# Extract email address from string in dataweave code?

Tags: dataweave

I am trying to extract email from imap connector as given below which is a string value.

```
"Star, Rocky[oracle]" <Rocky.Star@oracle.com>
```

Need to compare this email address with default sender email,which is configured in property file.

```
(default.check@oracle.com)
```

Can anyone help me know how better we can extract in dataweave and  compare accordingly.

Comment: Version info would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to compare, use `contains` (docs [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dw-core-functions-contains)):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java

var input        = '"Star, Rocky[oracle]" <Rocky.Star@oracle.com>'
var defaultEmail = "default.check@oracle.com"
---
if (input contains defaultEmail) 
  <do something>
else
  <do something else>
```